# Current menu item doesn't activate on home (first) section until movement

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and the Underscores starter theme to build a website for a client. The landing page is a one-pager with a navigation menu that slides to the correct section with anchor tags.

The issue is that for the first section the navigation link's "current" class doen't activate until I click the "home" link itself (the page doesn't move, only the class activates) or scroll a bit down. In the html the "home" section seems on the top of the viewport, so it should be activated on landing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add current class when page is loaded

```
$('.main-menu li:first-child').addClass('current');
```

Or event check if there is no selected items:

```
if ($('.main-menu .current').length == 0)
    $('.main-menu li:first-child').addClass('current');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger that with js jquery, somehting like

```
$('.yourFirstMenuElement').click();
```

Comment: Doesn't this activate it when I click? I'd need the "Home" section to be highlighted when  I land on the page without any interaction.

Comment: That is not an event function. That just triggers a click one time when the page is loaded.

Comment: Fixed it for home page landing. Although when I land with anchor links to other sections not home, the home click is not needed.

Comment: ok, maybe you can check if the url has a #... or a small delay you check if ScrollTop is on top, if so, trigger the click... but most optimized would be to have a scrollTop check only after page is loaded, to trigger the active link depending on that, just like the already script works somehow...